# Puppeteer: Get DOM element which isn't in the initial DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to figure out how to get the elements in e.g. a JS gallery that loads its images after they have been clicked on.

I'm using a demo of [Viewer.js](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/viewerjs/) as an example. The element with the classes `.viewer-move.viewer-transition` isn't in the initial DOM. After clicking on an image the element is available but if I use `$eval` the string is empty. If I open the console in the Puppeteer browser and execute `document.querySelector('.viewer-move.viewer-transition')` I get the element but in the code the element isn't available.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://fengyuanchen.github.io/viewerjs/');
    await page.click('[data-original="images/tibet-1.jpg"]');
    let viewer = await page.$eval('.viewer-move.viewer-transition', el => el.innerHTML);
    console.log(viewer);
})();
```

Comment: Try to ad a little delay after the click, so there is enough time for the element to load. await page.waitFor(number of milliseconds)

Comment: Doesn't work either =/ The string is still empty even if I wait 10s in between clicking and evaluating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the empty string because the element has no content so inner HTML is empty. `outerHTML` seems working:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://fengyuanchen.github.io/viewerjs/');

    await page.click('[data-original="images/tibet-1.jpg"]');
    await page.waitForSelector('.viewer-move.viewer-transition');

    const viewer = await page.$eval('.viewer-move.viewer-transition', el => el.outerHTML);
    console.log(viewer);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to return just `el` in the callback of `$eval` and got an empty object so I thought the element wasn't available in `page`.

Comment: Yes, the empty object is returned because HTML elements are not serializable and cannot be transfered as is from browser context to Node.js (puppeteer) context.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to wait until it is available, the most convenient method would be to use `await page.waitForSelector(".viewer-move.viewer-transition")` which would wait util the element is added to DOM, although this has the caveat that this continues execution the moment that the element is added to DOM, even if it is empty/hidden.

Comment: I've added `await page.waitForSelector(".viewer-move.viewer-transition")` in between `click()` and `$eval()` but `viewer` is still an empty string.